# Why is scope.apply required even though the function is called as part of event handler?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was trying to write a directive which allows us to delete values from a list. The HTML and Javascript code are as follows

HTML

```
<body ng-app="evalModule">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="newFriend"></input>
        <button ng-click="addFriend()">Add Friend</button>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
                <div class='deletable' index-value = {{$index}} delete-function="removeFriend(frndToRemove)"> {{$index}} {{friend}} </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function Ctrl1 ($scope) {
    $scope.friends = ["Jack","Jill","Tom"];

    $scope.addFriend = function () {
        $scope.friends.push($scope.newFriend);
    }

    $scope.removeFriend = function (indexvalue) {
        console.log(indexvalue);
        var index = $scope.friends.indexOf(indexvalue);
        $scope.friends.splice(indexvalue, 1);
    }
}

var evalModule = angular.module("evalModule",[]);

evalModule.directive('deletable', function(){
    return{
        restrict : 'C',
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        scope:{
            indexValue : '@indexValue',
            deleteFunction : '&'
        },
        template : '<div>'+
                        '<div> X </div>'+
                        '<div ng-transclude></div>'+
                    '</div>',
        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
            var del = angular.element(element.children()[0]);
            del.bind('click',deleteValue);

            function deleteValue () {
                var expressionHandler = scope.deleteFunction;
                expressionHandler({frndToRemove : scope.indexValue});
                console.log("deleteValue called with index" + attrs.indexValue);
                scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojpcw/p8umw/)

Why do I need to call scope.$apply even though the code is bound as an event to button click event. According to the docs here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope this should be part of "Angular realm".

Can somebody help me understand angular realm while clarifying the above? Any feedback on improving the above code would also appreciated.

Comment: button click is not `ng-click`.  Read about angular's compile > link phases.  that should give you a good overview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DavinTyron said, a button click event is an outside event, not part of "Angular realm". So you need to call `$scope.$apply()` in order to trigger a digest cycle and update the DOM.

In your case, though, you don't need to bind the click event manually. You may use `ng-click` instead:

```
template: '<div>'+
          '<div ng-click="delete()"> X </div>'+
          '<div ng-transclude></div>'+
          '</div>',
link: function(scope) {
    scope.delete = function () {
        scope.deleteFunction({frndToRemove : scope.indexValue});
        console.log("deleteValue called with index" + attrs.indexValue);                
    };
}
```

Since `ng-click` is being used, there's no need to call `$scope.$apply()`. Here's a [modified version](http://jsfiddle.net/p8umw/2/) of your jsFiddle.